# Random entities from Core Data to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, one-to-many, nspredicate

I'm trying to setup a core data model like this:
User-> Friends-> Albums -> Pictures
(Minus User, each of these is a to-many relationship)

I need to have the ability to randomly select X amount of pictures; preferably, I would like to avoid having to randomly choose a few Friends, then from those a few Albums and finally a few pictures- my core data predicate experience is quite limited so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do an "order by random" in an `NSFetchRequest`.  Seems like a decent idea, however, so you might want to [ask for it](http://bugreport.apple.com).

The closes you can get is to not specify any sort descriptors to the predicate and set a fetch limit.  Without a sort descriptor, the returned objects will come in some sort of probably-non-predictable order.

Comment: Yeah I figure I'd use setFetchLimit and get a set of objects.  My main issue however is figuring how to setup the NSPredicate to pull objects directly from the pictures.

I don't want to have to pull X number of Friends, then from those pull X number of albums then finally pull X number of Pictures.  I believe the answer is to use SUBQUERY but I'm not sure the best method to go that deep in a to-many relationship.

I considered changing the Pictures entity to include a relationship to 'User' then just asking for X number of pictures, but Core Data complains about no inverse to the relationship

Answer (score 0):

Hm I'm not so sure about this myself, but couldn't you do something with the following feature:

```
NSSet *myFetchedPictures;
[myFetchedPictures anyObject];
```

Maybe in a loop (don't forget to remove the object you used from the `NSSet`or you could end up with the same object again).

I'm quite new to CoreData myself, so if this is totally wrong please let me know :)